# how to select record from table where record have the most similar attribute from another table

Tags: php, mysql

TABLE A
result   select
A              a
B                   a
B                   b
C                   a
C                   b 
C             c

TABLE B

user      select

1                      a 
1                      b
2                      b 
2                      c

TABLE C 
user   result 
1         B
2         C
what mysql query should i have to use, if i want to do like this:

if user select a the result is A B C (because A B C have 'a' in column 'select')
if user select a b the result is B C (because A doesn't have 'b' in column 'select')
if user select a b c the result is C (because C have 'a b c' in column 'select')
if user select b c the result is C   (because A B doesn't have 'c' in column 'select')
if user select c the result is C     (because A B doesn't have 'c' in column 'select')

so it will select the record that have the most similar from what user selected and ignore the other record that doesn't match..
sorry for my english, i'm speak bahasa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  `result`
FROM tableA
WHERE   `select` IN ('a','b','c')
GROUP BY result
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

if a unique constraint was not enforce on `select` for every `result`, a `DISTINCT` is required.

```
SELECT  `result`
FROM tableA
WHERE   `select` IN ('a','b','c')
GROUP BY result
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `select`) = 3
```

Comment: thanks for the fast respond, so i have to use having count ??

Comment: @duta yes, because if you don't add that, it will not filter the rows that all matches to all condition.

Comment: by the way, how are tableB and tableC related to your question?

Comment: what user slected is insert to table B than from table B matching the record to table A, and the result insert to table C...